# Substituting an input according to a key provided by the user. Now it compiles fine and does what it's supposed to do as well

Tags: arrays, c, string, encryption

It's supposed to do the following

1. Ask for input : Stack (e.g)
2. Ask for key : qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm (e.g)
3. Convert into cipher text : Azqel

Here's the new updated code:

```
//Encrypting user input by using 26 character long alphabetic key provided by user
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char key[26];
char text[1000];
//Prompt user for key
do{
    printf("Provide a 26 character long key : ");
    scanf("%s", key);
    //If key is empty, exit code
    if(strlen(key) == 0){
        printf("Error: Empty input");
        return 1;
    }
    //If key is incomplete, prompt user again for complete key
    if(strlen(key)!= 26){
        printf("Error: Incomplete key\n");
    }
}while(strlen(key) != 26);
//If key has values other than alphabets, exit code
for(int i= 0, n= strlen(key); i<n; i++){
    if((key[i]< 'a' || key[i]> 'z') && (key[i]< 'A' || key[i]> 'Z')){
        printf("Error: Invalid key");
        return 2;
    }
}
//If key has repeated values, exit code
for(int i= 0; i< strlen(key); i++){
    for(int j= i+ 1; key[j]!= '\0'; j++){
        int x, y;
        if(islower(key[i])){
            x = key[i] - 'a';
        }
        else {
            x = key[i] - 'A';
        }
        if(islower(key[j])){
            y = key[j] - 'a';
        }
        else {
            y = key[j] - 'A';
        }
    if(x == y){
    printf("Error: Repeated characters in key");
    return 3;
    }
    }
}
//Prompt user for input
printf("Plaintext : ");
scanf("%s", text);
//If input is empty, exit code
if(strlen(text) == 0){
    printf("Error: Empty input");
    return 4;
}
printf("Ciphertext: ");
for(int i= 0, n= strlen(text); i< n; i++){
    //Encrypting small letters
    if(text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z'){
         printf("%c", key[text[i]-'a']);
    }
    //Encrypting capital letters
    else if(text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'){
         printf("%c", key[text[i]-'A']-('a'-'A'));
    }
    //Printing characters other than alphabets
    else{
        printf("%c", text[i]);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The bug where code was treating lower case characters and upper case characters differently even if they were same has been fixed now.
If the key is for example : qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbmM (it has the letters 'm' and 'M' but they were being treated as different characters)

Comment: As a side note: `gets()` is dangerous and shouldn't be used, read the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: Infinite innermost `do`-`while` loop.   It continues while `c == j`, but the body of the loop never changes `c` or `j`.    Also, rather than using magic number-based tests like `c>= 97 && c<= 122` (which are technically non-portable) try using standard functions such as `islower()` to check for a lowercase letter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   char s[1000];
   char t[26];
   printf("Text: ");
   scanf("%s", s);
   printf("Key: ");
   scanf("%s", t);
   for(int i= 0, n= strlen(s); i< n; i++){
      if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') printf("%c", t[s[i]-'a']);
      else printf("%c", t[s[i]-'A'] + ('A'-'a'));
   }
   return 0;
}
```

and as said in the comments, try not to use numbers like `97` and `122`, use `'a'` and `'z'` instead.

and for the bug mentioned in the updated code, instead of a simple check like `key[j] == key[i]` do this

```
int x, y;
if(islower(key[i])) x = key[i] - 'a';
else x = key[i] - 'A';
if(islower(key[j])) y = key[j] - 'a';
else y = key[j] - 'A';

if(x == y){
    printf("Error: Repeated characters in key");
    return 3;
}
```

or you can use a `bool check[26]`, traverse the key, make the value of a character true `if(islower(key[i])) check[key[i]-'a'] = true; else check[key[i]-'A'] = true;` and lastly check whether the entire bool array is true.